The workflow gets stuck after using `export DISPLAY=:99` and executing the `main.py` program
I have a Tkinter program that I want to run in a workflow to test it, but the workflow gets stuck in an infinite loop without any response, and I have to manually cancel the pipeline. Do you know how to resolve this?
.yml file:
- name: Display
  run: |
    export DISPLAY=:99
    Xvfb :99 &
    sleep 3
- name: Run Python
  run: |
    export DISPLAY=:99
    python main.py

Stucked in workflow:
Run export DISPLAY=:99
Error: The operation was canceled.

Problem is observed in this step:
export DISPLAY=:99
python main.py

After exporting and executing python programm, there is no reaction and workflow is stucked.
I tried separating it into individual tests, but that didn't help either. The problem persists.

There is no English verb "to stuck"; the word stuck is a participle of "to stick" which means to be unable to proceed.
